# How to calculate average for a column in tree view in odoo8?

Tags: odoo-8

In Xml:

```
<field name="percent_completion" avg="Avg. of Completion"/>
```

I used 'avg' but It does not show the average value on bottom of column.

Am also tried in python ,

```
percent_completion = fields.Integer('% Completion',group_operator = "avg")
```

how I find the average of the column in tree view.

Comment: group_operator for report

Comment: To get avg in tree view, `<field name="percent_completion" avg='Completion'/>`

Comment: I used  <field name="percent_completion" avg='Completion'/> also but average is not working in odoo 8.Can you tell any other options?

Comment: There is an example at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/crm_partner_assign/crm_portal_view.xml#L86 which uses `avg` on `odoo-8`